# css background repeat-x, strech-y

Tags: css

I have a striped background with a gradient which I want repeated in x and stretched in y. I thought this would work:

```
background: url(bg.jpg) repeat-x;
background-size: auto 100%;
```

But it either stretches in y or repeats in x, never both at same time:

[image]
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JCjEb

**Edit:** Note that I cannot simply repeat in y since the striped background also have a gradient (dark in bottom, lighter at top).

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wiahD - example b - is that what you need?

Comment: no, what I need is repeat-x and stretch-y. Example b does not stretch-y since if it did, it would be as "tall" as example a.

Comment: I meant example b - in the codepen link which  posted in my comment

Comment: oh, sorry. No, your example b is simply repeating in y. I replaced the striped background with golf pegs to make it more apparent. Your example b is the third example in my screenshot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving it width `auto`, give it the width of the image (`36px`).
http://codepen.io/thgaskell/pen/Bjsix

#### CSS

```
.c {
  background-size: 36px 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `background: url(bg.jpg) repeat;` without background-size. Here is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrLbc).

Comment: Since the bg also have a gradient (dark in bottom, light on top) I cannot do like this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you set the `background-size` to `auto 100%`, it's going to stretch the whole image proportionally, thus making the stripes too wide and distorted. Set the `x` part of the `background-size` to the width of the original image, and it won't stretch anymore.

```
.b {
  background: url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v63/promisedyouheaven/stripe2.gif) repeat;
  background-size: 35px 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BsAcY/

Answer (score 0):

Try `background: url(bg.png) center repeat-x;`

Not sure about IE8 and below though, if that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> .a {   background:
>   url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v63/promisedyouheaven/stripe2.gif)
>   repeat;   display:block;   width:500px; }

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

** HTML **

```
<div class="b"></div>
```

** CSS for bg image & gradient **

```
.b {     /* unprefixed gradient for example only*/
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%),
  url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v63/promisedyouheaven/stripe2.gif);

  background-repeat:repeat;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJruK)